# Is specific rotation a constant?

Tags: waves, visible-light, polarization, rotation

This is the formula for Specific Rotation of a solution.

[image]

Can I rearrange to make c as the subject and then say that theta is proportional to c?

[image]

If not, is there any other way in which I could relate the angle of rotation and concentration of solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $\theta$ is proportional to $c$ as long as all the other variables ($l, T, \lambda$) are kept constant.